# how to abort socket.io emit action or clean emit list.thanks

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

event 'progress' will emit buffer(big file buffer).When certain conditions i want to cancel or abort emit,and socket can't close.

socket.io will emit all event.

```
let io = socket.listen(server, { log: false, origins: '*:*' })
io.on('connection', (client) => {
 client.on('progress', (body) => {
    //body have file block buffer from other client,i want push buffer to third client.When certain conditions want to cancel or abort emit.
    io.to('jim-room').emit('/api/v1/client/done', body)
 }
}
```

thanks.